# Spring and dynamic inclusion of JSP files

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm starting building web apps in Spring 3 (and in J2EE) in general. 
Looking at the petclinic example I've seen that the programmer creates many JSP pieces, like header, includes, footer and then stitches them together using static inclusion. Anyway what I'd like is that I may have a base page, like `Base.jsp` and be able to include things like this:

```
<body>
 <jsp:include page="${subpage}"></jsp:include>
</body>
```

the reason is that I'd like a main page, then being able to put in the `ModelAndView` returned by the controller which parts of the pages display in each situation (with the data attached to it). This works, but it gives no errors in case `${subpage}` is not found, the jsp name is wrong or missing. I'd like more error checking...

Is this the best and recommended way to do this? And if this seems a good idea for what I've in mind, what's the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you have additional quotes in your `subpage`. Get rid of them. For example:

```
<c:set var="subpage" value="/jsp/index.jsp" />
```

If you have to set it in a controller or servlet - just use `request.setAttribute("subpage", "/jsp/index.jsp")`

Comment: impossible, subpage is changed in a controller class. Now way to set it from the JSP.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use Apache Tiles 2 integration for managing your JSP files. Spring has good integration support Apache Tiles. It also shows if there's an error in your page. I've put an example of it at http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-mvc-3-tiles-2-integration.html

Answer (score 0):

For error checking you can use:

```
<c:catch var="myException">
   <c:import url="${subpage}" />
</c:catch>
```

and later you can check it with:

```
<c:if test="${myException != null}">
...
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Sitemesh (http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh).  It is a servlet filter-based page layout system that is easy to use.   I have done a number of projects using it with Spring MVC and it worked very well.